# Bugged by de'bug

Tags: java

An unexpected token error occurs near the Class Database, yet everything in the syntax looks fine. I guess I made the error in the way I called the value from the class?

```
import de.bezier.data.sql.*; 

PostgreSQL pgsql;
Database 

void setup()
{
    size( 100, 100 );
    String user     = "user";
    String pass     = "pass";
    String database = "db";
    pgsql = new PostgreSQL( this, "127.0.0.1", database, user, pass );
    println ("ok");
}      

void draw()
{
    val1.update();
}
```

Token error here

```
Class Database 
{
    Float val;

    database (Float col) {
      val = col;
    }

    void update( ) 
    {
      //sets up database
      pgsql = new PostgreSQL( this, "127.0.0.1", database, user, pass );

        if ( pgsql.connect() )
        {
          pgsql.query( "SELECT col FROM table ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1; " );
          return( pgsql.getFloat("col") );
        }
        else
        {
          return float (col = 0);
        }
      }
}
```

Some text here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
 pgsql = new PostgreSQL( this, "127.0.0.1", database, user, pass )
```

is invoking a constructor. From the [documentation](http://bezier.de/processing/libs/sql/documentation/de/bezier/data/sql/PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL%28processing.core.PApplet,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you need to extend `processing.core.PApplet`. "this" refers to the current instance of "this" class.

Comment: I do see that. Does this mean that the 'this' needs replaced with processing.core.PApplet? I am not fully functional when reading the documentation.  My apologies for the silly questions. This is a new skill for me.

Comment: so what do you mean by extend? making more global to the program and remove it as a function?

Comment: What is the name of your class? You're using a library meant for a [PApplet](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html).

Comment: the language I am using is Processing. The library called brezier uses a class called PostgreSQL. Within this code, the function that calls upon the class is pgsql. If I interpret the authors work correctly. i am building upon the library's creator by using this code. my modifications have created enough problems for me in errors when i tried eliminating what i thought was useless code.

Comment: i think i understand. PostgreSQL.relevantMethod (...)?

Comment: No. Move it to your `setup()` section - here's the [example](https://github.com/fjenett/sql-library-processing/blob/master/examples/PostgreSQL_example1/PostgreSQL_example1.pde) and don't just modify the library (especially if it's your code that isn't working).

Comment: how would I move this code from setup to a helper file? It seems very touchy when I attempt that...

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't in Processing. Although you could write another class, and put it in its' `setup()`.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. Another more experienced programmer had the same issue when trying to transfer it. This code, based from the one you sent me, produced a mess of Java exceptions.

Comment: I have converted it into a class and it reads better, but I still get a new error. Thoughts? I re-edited the question above to reflect the changes.

Comment: What did you change? You cannot move this line `pgsql = new PostgreSQL( this, "127.0.0.1", database, user, pass )` out of `setup()`.

Comment: I just posted it to the class conversion. I also think I matched the structure of classes that was presented on Processing's web site. Somewhere I receive a token error, which to my understanding is related to syntax. But the syntax seems fine.

Comment: Feel free to email me.